# Unusually High Amount of TCP Connection Timeout Errors

Tags: go, tcp, connection, client-server, connection-timeout

I am using a Go TCP Client to connect to our Go TCP Server.

I am able to connect to the Server and run commands properly, but every so often there will be an unusually high amount of consecutive TCP connection errors reported by my TCP Client when trying to either connect to our TCP Server or sending a message once connected:

```
dial tcp kubernetes_node_ip:exposed_kubernetes_port:
connectex: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
host has failed to respond.

read tcp unfamiliar_ip:unfamiliar_port->kubernetes_node_ip:exposed_kubernetes_port
wsarecv: A connection attempt failed because the connected party did not properly
respond after a period of time, or established connection failed because connected
host has failed to respond.
```

I say "unusually high" because I assume that the number of times these errors occur should be very minimal (about 5 or less within the hour). Note that I am not dismissing the possibility of this being caused by connection instabilities, as I have also noticed that it is possible to run several commands in rapid succession without any errors.

However, I am still going to post my code in case I am doing something wrong.

Below is the code that my TCP Client uses to connect to our server:

```
serverAddress, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", kubernetes_ip+":"+kubernetes_port)
if err != nil {     
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

// Never stop asking for commands from the user.
for {
    // Connect to the server.
    serverConnection, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, serverAddress)
    if err != nil {         
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    defer serverConnection.Close()

    // Added to prevent connection timeout errors, but doesn't seem to be helping
    // because said errors happen within just 1 or 2 minutes.
    err = serverConnection.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Minute))
    if err != nil {         
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    // Ask for a command from the user and convert to JSON bytes...

    // Send message to server.
    _, err = serverConnection.Write(clientMsgBytes)
    if err != nil {
        err = merry.Wrap(err)
        fmt.Println(merry.Details(err))
        continue
    }

    err = serverConnection.CloseWrite()
    if err != nil {
        err = merry.Wrap(err)
        fmt.Println(merry.Details(err))
        continue
    }

    // Wait for a response from the server and print...
}
```

Below is the code that our TCP Server uses to accept client requests:

```
// We only supply the port so the IP can be dynamically assigned:
serverAddress, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", ":"+server_port)
if err != nil {     
    return err
}

tcpListener, err := net.ListenTCP("tcp", serverAddress)
if err != nil {     
    return err
}

defer tcpListener.Close()

// Never stop listening for client requests.
for {
    clientConnection, err := tcpListener.AcceptTCP()
    if err != nil {         
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    go func() {
        // Add client connection to Job Queue.
        // Note that `clientConnections` is a buffered channel with a size of 1500.
        // Since I am the only user connecting to our server right now, I do not think
        // this is a channel blocking issue.
        clientConnections <- clientConnection
    }()
}
```

Below is the code that our TCP Server uses to process client requests:

```
defer clientConnection.Close()

// Added to prevent connection timeout errors, but doesn't seem to be helping
// because said errors happen within just 1 or 2 minutes.
err := clientConnection.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Minute))
if err != nil {     
    return err
}

// Read full TCP message.
// Does not stop until an EOF is reported by `CloseWrite()`
clientMsgBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(clientConnection)
if err != nil {
    err = merry.Wrap(err)
    return nil, err
}

// Process the message bytes...
```

My questions are:

1. Am I doing something wrong in the above code, or is the above decent enough for basic TCP Client-Server operations?
2. Is it okay that both the TCP Client and TCP Server have code that defers closing their one connection?
3. I seem to recall that calling `defer` inside a loop does nothing. How do I properly close Client connections before starting new ones?

Some extra information:

- Said errors are not logged by the TCP Server, so aside from
  connection instabilities, this might also be a
  Kubernetes/Docker-related issue.

Comment: your code for client, creates one connection to server and then without waiting for anything proceeds to make the next connection. Is this what you want from the code? if so, then high number of tcp connections could be a result of that.

Comment: @whitespace Sorry for the confusion. I have updated the description above. The Client waits for a response from the server and prints it to the screen before closing the connection and trying again.

Comment: Looking at your code on the client, the connection does not get closed. The defer executes when the function returns, not when an iteration of the foor loop ends. Also, you don't need to open new connections all the time. You can keep a single one.

Comment: @FrançoisP. Yeah, I am in the process of fixing my bad `defer`. Also, what do you mean I can keep a single connection for my client? Shouldn't it be that Clients do a fire-and-forget sort of thing? (I'm trying to simulate requests from the UI which end as soon as they get what they want)

Comment: Establishing a connection has an overhead. You could just keep a single connection open and build a protocol on top, to handle sort of request/response mechanism this is usually what you do.

Comment: @FrançoisP. Ah, so each client should only have 1 connection, which will get closed anyway once the clients themselves are closed? Has that always been the norm?

Comment: One, or a pool of connections if you have high load. But opening and closing connections all the time is not efficient.

Comment: @FrançoisP. I see, I'll look into that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this piece of code does not act as you think it does. The defer statement on the connection close will only happen when the function returns, not when an iteration ends. So as far as I can see here, you are creating a lot of connections on the client side, it could be the problem.

```golang
serverAddress, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", kubernetes_ip+":"+kubernetes_port)
if err != nil {     
    fmt.Println(err)
    return
}

// Never stop asking for commands from the user.
for {
    // Connect to the server.
    serverConnection, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, serverAddress)
    if err != nil {         
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    defer serverConnection.Close()

    // Added to prevent connection timeout errors, but doesn't seem to be helping
    // because said errors happen within just 1 or 2 minutes.
    err = serverConnection.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Minute))
    if err != nil {         
        fmt.Println(err)
        continue
    }

    // Ask for a command from the user and send to the server...

    // Wait for a response from the server and print...
}
```

I suggest to write it this way:

```
func start() {
    serverAddress, err := net.ResolveTCPAddr("tcp", kubernetes_ip+":"+kubernetes_port)
    if err != nil {     
        fmt.Println(err)
        return
    }
    for {
        if err := listen(serverAddress); err != nil {
            fmt.Println(err)
        }
    }
}

func listen(serverAddress string) error {
     // Connect to the server.
     serverConnection, err := net.DialTCP("tcp", nil, serverAddress)
     if err != nil {         
         fmt.Println(err)
         continue
     }

    defer serverConnection.Close()

    // Never stop asking for commands from the user.
    for {
        // Added to prevent connection timeout errors, but doesn't seem to be helping
        // because said errors happen within just 1 or 2 minutes.
        err = serverConnection.SetDeadline(time.Now().Add(10 * time.Minute))
        if err != nil {         
           fmt.Println(err)
           return err
        }

        // Ask for a command from the user and send to the server...

        // Wait for a response from the server and print...
    }
}
```

Also, you should keep a single connection open, or a pool of connections, instead of opening and closing the connection right away. Then when you send a message you get a connection from the pool (or the single connection), and you write the message and wait for the response, then you release the connection to the pool.

Something like that:

```golang
res, err := c.Send([]byte(`my message`))
if err != nil {
    // handle err
}

// the implementation of send
func (c *Client) Send(msg []byte) ([]byte, error) {
    conn, err := c.pool.Get() // returns a connection from the pool or starts a new one
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }
    // send your message and wait for response
    // ...
    return response, nil
}
```

Comment: Hi! I updated my description above. I like the idea of only having 1 connection, but my problem with this is that I am calling `serverConnection.CloseWrite()` to signal to the server that I am now done sending my message. The problem is that I can't seem to reuse a connection once `CloseWrite()` has been called on it. Any advice on this situation?

Comment: Just use `Write`, `CloseWrite` shuts down the writing side of the Unix domain connection. You cannot write anymore after `CloseWrite`.

Comment: `SetDeadline` could be done outside the loop, since there is only one `serverConnection` here.

Comment: @FrançoisP. It seems I can't call only `Write` because the Server is using this to read Client messages: `clientMsgBytes, err := ioutil.ReadAll(connection)`. This seems to rely on `CloseWrite()` being called (it expects an `EOF` before stopping). Any advice on this? I can modify both the Client and Server codes.

Comment: You can't change the server code? The best would be to use a bufio.Reader or bufio.Scanner on the server side, and just read till the next '\n' for example. https://golang.org/pkg/bufio/#Scanner 
ioutil.ReadAll is a bad idea. In the end, HTTP might be even more performant than what you are doing, because HTTP does keep connections alive.

Comment: @FrançoisP. I can modify both Client and Server code, so I can probably implement any solution. Also, the project direction is to use TCP instead of HTTP. That one detail is out of my control.

Comment: I understand completely that you want to use TCP. I'm just saying that if don't keep connections alive you will have something slower than a HTTP server that keeps connections alive :)